# Simultaneously indexing fields and a slice using `h5py`

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

Given an H5Py file of the following type

```
In [41]: d.shape
Out[41]: (37450461,)

In [42]: d.dtype 
Out[42]: dtype([('transaction', '<i8'), ('sender', '<i8'), ('recipient', '<i8'),
                ('timestamp', '<i8'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

I would like to get out a few fields over just a few entries.  I'm looking for something like the following:

```
In [43]: d[['timestamp', 'value'], :5]
```

Sadly this raises an error.  I can break the query up into multiple parts and it works:

```
In [46]: d[:5][['timestamp', 'value']]
```

But this is inefficient.

#### Question

Is there any way to efficiently select a few fields and a few entries from a structured array stored in HDF5 using `h5py`?

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out my answer as I was writing the question

```
>>> d['timestamp', 'value', :5]
```